# Looping through a dropdown list

Tags: vba

I have two spreadsheets. Spreadsheet #1 shows a list of 25 items (in cells A4:A28). Spreadsheet #2 is a calculation workbook that has the same list of 25 items in a dropdown. The dropdown is located in cell B7. Spreadsheet #2 updates every time a selection is updated in this dropdown. What I want to do is to loop through every selection in the dropdown in Spreadsheet 2, and copy the sum of the total line (row C68:Q68) and paste into spreadsheet #1 for the corresponding item (cell B4 for the first item on the list). Then move on to the 2nd item in the list, and so on.

I have the following codes:

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(ActiveWorkbook("Spreadsheet2").Worksheet("Tab2").Range("B7").Validation.Formula1)
        For Each c In inputRange
        ActiveWorkbook("Spreadsheet1").Worksheets("Tab1").Range("B4").Value = Application.Sum(ActiveWorkbook("Spreadsheet1").Worksheet("Tab1").Range(Cells(68, 3), Cells(68, 17)))

        Next c
End Sub
```

I have trouble going between two sheets and actually looping through the list in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are not being explicit which sheet you are referring to when you are accessing the `Cells` object. It defaults to the `ActiveWorkbook`, which may or may not be what is needed. Try something like this out, see if that works.

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c          As Range
    Dim ws1        As Worksheet
    Dim ws2        As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Spreadsheet1").Worksheets("Tab2")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Spreadsheet2").Worksheets("Tab2")

    Set inputRange = Evaluate(ws2.Range("B7").Validation.Formula1)

    For Each c In inputRange
        '.Cells will use whatever the activeworkbook is,
        'it is preferable to be explicit which sheet you want to work with
        ws1.Range("B4").Value = Application.Sum(ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(68, 3), ws2.Cells(68, 17)))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That makes a lot of sense to me. Now I am stuck on the referencing the drop down box. I have the following code <Set inputRange = Evaluate(ws2.DropDowns("Drop Down 1").Validation.Formula1)>. I am getting an error that says: Object doesn't support this property or method.